# How do I run shellcode on Linux kernel 5.8+?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, 64bit, assembly

The assembly code I'm trying to run is simply a syscall 60.

```bsh
# exit.s
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

xor rax, rax
mov al, 0x3c
xor rdi, rdi
xor rdi, 1

syscall
```

assembling this with `as exit.s -o exit.o`, linking with `ld exit.o -o exit` and `objdump -d exit` to get the final code.

```c
// ret.c
const char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x48\x83\xf7\x01\x0f\x05";
int main() {
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();
}
```

I compile using `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -no-pie -o ret ret.c`

On Manjaro Linux (kernel 5.10) and Ubuntu (kernel 5.8), I get a seg fault when trying to run the final executable.

I tried the same on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4) and it works flawlessly.

I did some research, and it looks like [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9fccc5c0c99f238aa1b0460fccbdb30a887e7036) might have changed the behavior, but I'm not sure.

My question: **How do I get the above code to work on the latest kernel version?**

Comment: Your code is not supposed to work, and it is a good thing if it doesn't. If you can get it to work, you have managed to bypass the protection that was put there on purpose.

Comment: `man mprotect` to get details on how to make the shellcode executable.

Comment: Try with `__attribute__((section(".text"))) const char shellcode[] = ...`. Yes this will defeat the "shellcode/exploit" idea, but (as already mentioned) it's just how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re asking for an executable stack, putting your code there will make it executable:

```c
int main() {
    const char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x48\x83\xf7\x01\x0f\x05";
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the page protections on the page(s) containing the shellcode:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x48\x83\xf7\x01\x0f\x05";

int main() {
  long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  void *page_start = (void *) ((long) shellcode & -page_size);
  if (mprotect(page_start, page_size * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC)) {
    perror("mprotect");
  } else {
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();
  }
}
```

The whole point of changes such as [the one you found](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9fccc5c0c99f238aa1b0460fccbdb30a887e7036) is to fix whole classes of vulnerabilities. Even with the approach above, you won’t be able to inject code into a running process and execute it if the process isn’t “cooperating” to some extent (by requesting executable stacks).